# Is my GPU rendering two screen at a time

Tags: windows-8, display, gpu, vga

I am using a Dell Inspiron 14r, whose display screen is not working properly. It's just a white and dotted black screen, right now I can't buy a new one, **I am using Window 8**. So I made my laptop connect with an old PC monitor using a VGA cable.
But now my laptop overheats faster; I can't even play games which leads the laptop to power off after some time. So I want to ask: is my GPU rendering two screens at a time?

1. Defective laptop screen.
2. Monitor connected via VGA.

If so, then what can I do to render only my monitor screen via VGA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible it's still rendering to both.  The laptop doesn't know it's on board monitor is broken.

To check this, with the VGA monitor plugged in, hold down the Windows Key and press P.  This will bring up projector options.  You can then see the options, one of which will be "Projector Only"

Choose this and the laptop will output to the second screen only.

Comment: I am using windows 8, on pressing window+p, i have options-second screen only which work for me. there is no light on laptop  screen now. Hope it will consume less GPU.

Comment: @Kharak - You should edit your question so the community understands what version of Windows you are using.